# Why does Django add 'IS NOT NULL' to SQL clause?

Tags: python, django

I have model:

```
class Profile:
    ...
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
    ...
```

When I run queryset:

```
Profile.objects.exclude(phone='', phone__isnull=True).values('phone')
```

It create SQL code:

```
SELECT "user_profile_profile"."phone" FROM "user_profile_profile" WHERE NOT ("user_profile_profile"."phone" IS NULL AND "user_profile_profile"."phone" = '' AND "user_profile_profile"."phone" IS NOT NULL); args=('',)
```

And it is wrong because it return all phone include phone=None and phone=''.

Comment: What do you want to query actually ?

Comment: I expect it is `NOT ("user_profile_profile"."phone" = '') AND NOT ("user_profile_profile"."phone" IS NULL)`. And why was `"user_profile_profile"."phone" IS NOT NULL` added?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to split the `exclude` condition to two parts:

```
Profile.objects.exclude(phone='').exclude(phone__isnull=True).values('phone')
```

or use `Q` object

```
from django.db.models import Q
Profile.objects.exclude(Q(phone='')|Q(phone__isnull=True)).values('phone')
```